# Ignoring spaces in Vigenere Cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I've coded an encryption and decryption program for vigenere cipher but I'm stuck when it comes to involve spaces. What condition could I use to overcome it and ignore it completely

```
print("Enter the string to be encrypted")
s=input()
print("Enter the key for encryption")
t=input()
r=0
s=list(s)
t=list(t)
key=[]
encrypted=[]
decrypted=[]
#This is the loop for making the key string
for i in range(0,len(s),len(t)):
    r=i
    for j in range(0,len(t),1):
        if(i<len(s)):
            if(len(key)<len(s)):
                    key.append(t[j])
        i=i+1
    i=r
print("The encrypted key is: ")
key=''.join(key)
print(key)
#This is the code for encrypting the message with the key string
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    x = (ord(s[i]) + ord(key[i])) % 26
    x += ord('A') 
    encrypted.append(chr(x))
print("The encrypted string is: ")
encrypted=''.join(encrypted)
print(encrypted)
#For decryption
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    x = (ord(encrypted[i]) - ord(key[i])+26) % 26
    x += ord('A') 
    decrypted.append(chr(x))
print("The decrypted string is: ")
decrypted=''.join(decrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

Here Key string refers to as ->

STRING INPUT - WATERMELON

Key - LEMON

Key string - LEMONLEMON

But it isn't working for sentences. I tried putting in code like

```
if(s[i]==' '):
    continue
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Code is not usable, beside that your problem is that you are creating the key matching the string with spaces you should remove spaces before encrypting.

Comment: the code is usable with only Uppercase characters and uppercase keys but without spaces, also how would I put spaces after encrypting during the decryption process...editing it to make it work, posting it may have changed it a bit

Comment: it's not about that, try copy-pasting the code to a new file and you'll see what I mean. you most likely have mixed-indent or something, look at the first loop,  the ```r=i``` is "over indented

Comment: The code is fixed now hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, hope it's not too python2

````
from itertools import cycle
# if python2 uncomment the following
# from itertools import izip as zip

# you can replace these with calls for input() 
data = "attack at dawn"
key = "lemon"

# sanitize input
data = "".join(data.upper().split()) # trick to remove all white-space chars
key = key.upper()


print data
print key

ord_A = ord('A')

# encripting 
encrypted = []

# looping together the input and the key
# cycle gives an infinite loop over an iterable 
for dc, kc in zip(data, cycle(key.upper())):
    ec = ord_A + (ord(dc) + ord(kc)) % 26
    encrypted.append(chr(ec))
encrypted =  "".join(encrypted) 
print(encrypted)

# decrypting
decrypted = []
for ec, kc in zip(encrypted, cycle(key.upper())):
    dc = ord_A + (ord(ec) - ord(kc)) % 26
    decrypted.append(chr(dc))
decrypted =  "".join(decrypted)
print(decrypted)```
````

Comment: what is izip ? Tried copy pasting and trying but it shows an error for izip

Comment: sorry that seems to be python2 specific, `zip` joins together multiple "iterables" returning a list of tuples where each element/tuple contains the n-th element of each of the arguments, the `izip` returns a "generator-like" object instead of the full list thous having a smaller footprint, seems that in python3 the `izip` was removed since `zip` is already "optimized".